# NGINX containerized server failes to access existing folder and returns Error 404

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, yaml

I'm trying to deploy containerized NGINX server on an AWS EC2 instance to share a directory content over HTTP.
I'm using `helm` command to deploy the container:

```
helm install nginx  on_premise_configuration/nginx --set ingress.hostname=xxx.yyy.cloud -f ./on_premise_configuration/demo/nginx-values.yml
```

`nginx-values.yml` content as follows:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
service:
  type: ClusterIP

containerPorts:
  http: 80

serverBlock: |-
  server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    location / {
      root /out;
      autoindex on;
    }
  }
readinessProbe:
  enabled: false

livenessProbe:
  enabled: false

containerSecurityContext:
  enabled: true
  runAsUser: 0
  runAsNonRoot: false
```

Directory `/out` and file `/out/index.html` do exist and have full 777 access rights.

Deployed pod is running fine:

```
[root@xxxx]# kubectl get pods
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-bbff6c589-7cd7b   1/1     Running   0          2m8s
```

However any HTTP request attempt is rejected with error 404:

```
[root@xxxx]# kubectl logs nginx-bbff6c589-7cd7b
nginx 22:08:08.35
nginx 22:08:08.35 Welcome to the Bitnami nginx container
nginx 22:08:08.36 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-nginx
nginx 22:08:08.36 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-nginx/issues
nginx 22:08:08.36
nginx 22:08:08.36 INFO  ==> ** Starting NGINX setup **
nginx 22:08:08.37 INFO  ==> Validating settings in NGINX_* env vars
nginx 22:08:08.39 INFO  ==> Initializing NGINX
nginx 22:08:08.40 INFO  ==> ** NGINX setup finished! **

nginx 22:08:08.41 INFO  ==> ** Starting NGINX **
2021/03/29 22:08:37 [error] 36#36: *1 "/out/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.42.0.111, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx.yyy.cloud"
10.42.0.111 - - [29/Mar/2021:22:08:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 180 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36 Edg/89.0.774.57"
```

No matter what request is for - individual file or directory listing.

I re-iterate once again - the server is running on AWS EC2 instance and I might've missed some AWS specific configuration.

I've tried different yml versions but nothing is working and I actually run out of ideas.

I would really appreciate for any advice how to resolve it.

Comment: I'm not allowed to edit but title has to be changed to "NGINX containerized server failes to access existing folder on host and returns Error 404"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I've realized that yml file doesn't contain mounting points between host folder and internal pod's filesystem.
In fact NGINX was searching /out folder inside the pod while I was trying to share the host folder.

Perhaps the original question needs to be updated to highlight that host folder to be shared by using contenerized NGINX

Anyway, once I've updated yml file everything started working. correct nginx-values.yml version:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
service:
  type: ClusterIP

containerPorts:
  http: 80

serverBlock: |-
  server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    location /output {
      root /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/;
      autoindex on;
    }
  }
readinessProbe:
  enabled: false

livenessProbe:
  enabled: false

containerSecurityContext:
  enabled: true
  runAsUser: 0
  runAsNonRoot: false

extraVolumes:
  - name: centos
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /out
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory

extraVolumeMounts:
  - name: centos
    mountPath: /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/output
```

the above yml is mounting host folder `/out` to pod's folder `/opt/bitnami/nginx/html/output`